# "double free" exception with Cocos2d, empty stack trace

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've received the following crash in my logs a few times now:

```
Aftermath(2645,0x4bdd000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1903ccb0: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I did as instructed, and here's what I got; note the crashed thread #17

[image]

I hit continue, and here's what I then get:

[image]

Comment: report this as a bug on github, ideally with a simple test project to reproduce the issue

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I can certainly report it, but I don't have the faintest idea how to repro. In the last ~10+ hours of testing, I've only seen it these two times... and my project is by no means simple :( Is there anything else I could do to help provide information/context?

Comment: run the xcode analyze build and fix any issues it reports, or at least confirm they won't be a problem